# Ошибка 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable | Парсинг

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sqlite3

from urllib3 import proxy_from_url

url = "https://www.sulpak.kz/f/smartfoniy"
base_url = "https://www.sulpak.kz"
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text



soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
container = soup.select_one("ul.goods-container")


products = container.find_all("li")

urls = []

for product in products :
    url = product.select_one("div.goods-photo a")["href"]
    urls.append(base_url + url)
    print(urls)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь запарсить сайт и при попытке получить ссылки на товар, выходит ссылка и еще пару ссылок на этот же товар, только в другом цвете тип, а мне этого не надо, нужно дальше идти после получения первой ссылки на товар, и еще вот такая ошибка

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: products = container.find_all("li", class_="tile-container")

Comment: url = product.a["href"] писать меньше ))